# Escape variable for zsh's `print -P`

Tags: zsh, quoting

I was looking for a way to escape a variable containing format specifiers and special characters like quotes, backslashes and line breaks so that when passing it to `print -P` it'll print out literally.

So essentially I want these two to print the same:

```
> cat file.txt
```

```
> my_var="$(cat file.txt)"
> print -P "${<magic>my_var}"
```

A good example file for test cases I used is this:

```
Backslash \
Double Backslash \\

Single Quote '
Double Quote "

-----------------------
Escaped Linebreak \n
-----------------------

Color codes: %F{red}not red%f

Variable expansion $SHELL
```

Closest I got is `${${(q+)my_var}//\%/%%}` though that has issues with quotes, linebreaks, backslashes and variable expansion:

```
$'Backslash Double Backslash \

Single Quote '
Double Quote "

-----------------------
Escaped Linebreak \n
-----------------------

Color codes: %F{red}not red%f

Variable expansion /usr/bin/zsh'
```

I am aware of `printf '%s\n' "$my_var"`. However in practice there's a lot of actual formatting going on in the `print -P` around the variable, so this isn't useful to me. Using `print -P` around the variable and `printf` for the actual variable sadly also doesn't work as there are cases where string manipulation is applied to the contents of the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${(q)…}` and its variants use `'…'`, `"…"` or `$'…'` quoting, but `print -P` doesn't do any quote expansion, only backslash expansion and prompt expansion (which is percent-escape expansion, plus substitutions if `prompt_subst` is enabled). So I don't think `${(q)…}` can help here.

With `prompt_subst` disabled, you need to protect backslashes and percent signs. With `prompt_subst` enabled, you also need to protect dollars and backquotes.

```
if [[ -o prompt_subst ]]; then
  print -P -- "${${${${my_var//\\/\\\\\\\\}//\%/%%}//\$/\\\\\$}//\`/\\\\\`}"
else
  print -P -- "${${my_var//\\/\\\\}//\%/%%}"
fi
```

Comment: Could it be that you forgot the variable in the upper case?

Comment: If you make it `print -rP`, you don't need to escape backslashes.

Comment: If `prompt_bang` is enabled, you'll need to escape `!`.

Comment: With current versions of zsh, you'd also need to do the substitutions under `set +o multibyte` as otherwise you'd still get a command injection vulnerability with `promptsubst` in some locales. For instance, on my system where the `zh_HK` uses the BIG5-HKSCS charset (and where the encoding of `ε` is `$'\xa3\x60'`), `my_var=$'\xa3\`reboot;#\xa8\`' LC_ALL=zh_HK zsh -o promptsubst ./that-code` reboots.

Answer (score 1):

If the aim is to print some strings, part of which must undergo prompt expansion, or `\x` expansion, part of which don't, rather than doing:

```
print -P -- $string_to_undergo_both \
            ${string_to_undergo_prompt//\\/\\\\} \
            ${string_to_undergo_backslash//complex-brittle-expression} \
            ${string_to_undergo_none//complex-brittle-expression} \
```

You could break it down to:

```
print  -P -n -- $string_to_undergo_both' '
print -rP -n -- $string_to_undergo_prompt' '
print     -n -- $string_to_undergo_backslash' '
print -r     -- $string_to_undergo_none
```

(beware that with `print -rP`, if the `promptsubst` option is enabled, `\` is still special as it's used to escape the `$`, `` ` `` and itself, so `print -rP '\\'` would then output `\` instead of `\\`).

Or call `print -r --` which prints `r`aw (disables `\x` expansion which is on by default in `print` for compatibility with the Korn shell), but use parameter expansion flags to enable prompt expansion or backslash expansion where needed:

```
print -r -- ${(g[o]%)string_to_undergo_both} \
            ${(%)string_to_undergo_prompt} \
            ${(g[o])string_to_undergo_backslash} \
            $string_to_undergo_none
```

You can also enable those for literal text (not in variables), by using `${(flags):-literal-text}` (`${(%):-%F{red}}` for instance for prompt expansion), or the `$'...'` form of quotes for backslash expansion.

See also the `%%` parameter expansion flag for full prompt expansion (including the applying of the dangerous `promptsubst` when enabled), and `e` to perform parameter expansions, command substitutions and arithmetic expansions.

With `printf`, backslash expansion is performed in the format argument and in arguments for the `%b` format directive (but for the latter in the `echo` style, not the normal C style). There is no format directive for prompt expansion though.

With prompt expansion however, you can also pass verbatim text (though beware the non-printable characters such as control ones are converted to some visual representation (`\n` for newline, `^[` for ESC, `\ufffe` for U+FFFE for instance) with the `$psvar` array.

```
$ psvar=( '\\' %% )
$ print -P 'first is %F{red}%1v%f, second is %F{green}%2v%f'
first is \\, second is %%
```

So, you could do some sort of prompt-expansion-enabled `printf` with something like:

```
pprintf() {
  local psvar=("${(@)argv[2,-1]}")
  print -P -- "$1"
}
```

```
$ pprintf 'cwd: %~, host: %m, arbitrary printable string: "%1v"' '\\%%'
cwd: ~, host: myhost, arbitrary printable string: "\\%%"
```

(here also doing backslash expansion, add `-r` to disable it).

Comment: Not quite applicable to my situation, but I like that approach!

Comment: I also find it very curious that line breaks are printed as `\n` with the `psvar` method.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't realised that. It look like non-printable characters are converted to some visual representations (U+FFFE to `\ufffe`, ESC to `^[`...).

Comment: @BrainStone, it does actually make sense: those are meant to be used in your prompt, so if control characters were sent asis, it would mess up the line editor display.